# ASP.NET page 'Page_Load' firing before Master Page's 'Page_Load' event?

Tags: c#, asp.net

On my Master Page, I have a little method in the `Page_Load` event that checks to see if a user is logged in, and redirects them to the Login page if not.

The problem is that for some of my pages the `Page_Load` events presume a users logged are in, and these events seems to fire before the login check in the master page, which causes errors.

What are some ways around this? Any events I can use other than Page_Load in my pages, that'll fire *after* the master page?

Comment: Are you not using Forms-Authentication? You only have to specify a LoginUrl to automatically redirect to your Login.aspx on any page if user is not authenticated or session is timed out. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.loginurl.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have a rich [Page Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) with lots of events to use.
Perhaps you could use `Page_Init` to check if the user is logged-in in the Master Page.
Or use `Page_PreRender` in the other pages.

Comment: Fantastic - changed the check to Page_Init and it now works perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you need things to occur in the MasterPage Page_Load before the page events, use the Page_PreRender

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

in the actual page.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to check whether the user is logged in for those features, by doing: `if (this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true) { .. }`.  Nothing can be assumed, which is what you are experiencing.  You could also move your login check to Page_Init, or even move it to an HTTP module that runs on every page load; there you have access to a wide array of events including application authentication/authorization.

If you are using forms authentication, you can use the configuration file to drive this instead, via the authorization element.

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<location path="login.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

HTH.