# ASP.NET how to store user login data in the APP

Tags: asp.net

Just wondering what the best way to store user login data on successful login in my application. I.e. when logged in at the moment I do something like this in my login script

```
                            Session("loggedIn") = "Yes"
                            Session("userName") = reader_login("useremail").ToString()
                            Session("userId") = reader_login("user_ID").ToString()
                            Session("firstName") = reader_login("firstName").ToString()
                            Session("lastName") = reader_login("lastName").ToString()
```

And then I use these session variables on my scripts, but just noticed that every time I want to use some of these session variables I do need to check if they are nut null before calling them, seems a bit clumsy to repeat these for a lot of my .aspx pages. Is there a better way to do this ?

EDIT :

Also I am wondering why do I need to add the IS NUll check for the session on each script I use session variables I put the check in the master page but noticed I still get null exception in my usercontrol which is referenced in my master page but does not have the IS null check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load this through a single object which you put in the Session. This will remove all your strings as you can just set properties. Also you can check if the object is available in the session, if it's not the user is not logged in?

```
public class CurrentUserObject
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public CurrentUserObject(string userName, string userID, string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        UserName = userName;
        UserID = userID;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

You can instantiate this object and store it in Session("CurrentUser") or something. If you request this session variable and it turns out to be null, your user is not logged in. I would advise you to do this in a master page or something by the way to avoid duplication of this code.

Comment: This sounds can you give an example of Session Object

Comment: hey, if I store this Session("CurrentUser") object how Can i retrieve i.e. the variable Username From it ? I.e Session("CurrentUser").Username ? Also I agree with checking for the null check in the master page but I have found if I dont put the null check i.e in my usercontrol and call a session variable in there, and if the session is dead I get null point exception, how come the master page doesnt catch that ?

Comment: You probably do the check in the master page to late in your page lifecycle. If your user is nog loggedin you can redirect directly before the child controls are constructed. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593652/asp-net-page-page-load-firing-before-master-pages-page-load-event

Comment: hey kip at the moment I do the check in the Pre_Init Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        '#Check that User is Logged in, if not redirect to login page
        If (Session("userId") Is Nothing) Or (Session("logsID") Is Nothing) Then
            Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("site_base_url").ToString & "login/", False)
        End If

Comment: I added this Null check the my master page in pre_render, but I still get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. on Session("userName").ToString() in my usercontrol how is this possible ?

Comment: you should now use Session("CurrentUser").UserName (or make a helper class or something)

Comment: Yeah regardless thekip I get that bject reference not set to an instance of an object on the session variables on my usercontrol, even tho I have the null check in the masterpage.

Comment: The only way that can happen if there's something wrong in your page lifecycle. The check in your master page is done after your control gets loaded. You are sure you use the correct session variable I suppose (refactor it into a constant string or create a helper for it).

Answer (score 2):

Session is not the way to check whether user is authenticated or not. Session may be cleared on demand by administrator when clearing app pool, or by the low memory on server. You won't wish to log out user in such cases. The builtin and reccommended way for doing this in ASP.NET is storing data in authentication cookie. Once the user is logged in, you issue the cookie that contains all the data, including user id, name, etc. And then, you don't have to check every property in session for null, more simple - you just check if the user is authenticated - then you've got the data, else -not. And the other benefit, if you substitute builtin principal with custom one, you can define strongly typed object that holds user data, no more casting from objects extracted from session. Here're the examples for defining custom principal with forms authentication

First, let's define custom MyIdentity and MyPrincipal

```
 public class MyIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        private FormsAuthenticationTicket _Ticket;
        private int _userId = 0;

        public FormsAuthenticationTicket Ticket
        {
            get { return _Ticket; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Ticket.Name; }
        }

        public int UserId
        {
            get
            {
                if (_userId == 0)
                    _userId = Convert.ToInt32(_Ticket.UserData.Split("|".ToCharArray())[0]);

                return _userId;
            }
        }

        public Identity(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            this._Ticket = ticket;
        }

        public string AuthenticationType
        {
            get { return "Custom"; }
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get { return UserId > 0; }
        }
    }
```

Then the MyPrincipal that holds MyIdentity

```
public class MyPrincipal : IPrincipal
    {
        private MyIdentity _Identity;

        public Principal(MyIdentity identity)
        {
            _Identity = identity;
        }

        public IIdentity Identity
        {
            get { return _Identity; }
        }

        public bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then substitute original forms user with the custom one. In Global.asax

```
private void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPrincipal usr = HttpContext.Current.User;
        // If we are dealing with an authenticated forms authentication request  
        if (usr.Identity.IsAuthenticated && usr.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Forms")
        {
            FormsIdentity formsIdentity = usr.Identity as FormsIdentity;
            // Create a CustomIdentity based on the FormsAuthenticationTicket               
            IIdentity identity = new MyIdentity(formsIdentity.Ticket);
            IPrincipal principal = new MyPrincipal(identity);
            // Attach the CustomPrincipal to HttpContext.User and Thread.CurrentPrincipal
            HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
        }
    }
```

Define method for issuing forms authentication ticket. Later, the custom MyIdentity class will extract userId and other methods from userData.

```
public static HttpCookie GetAuthCookie(string userName, string userData, bool createPersistentCookie, HttpSessionStateBase session)
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(ticket.Version, ticket.Name, ticket.IssueDate, ticket.Expiration, ticket.IsPersistent, userData, session.SessionID);
            authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);

            return authCookie;
        }
```

When the user is checked and is authenticated, return them authentication cookie

```
 Response.Cookies.Add(AuthenticationCookie.GetAuthCookie(model.UserName, GetUserInfo(model.UserName, passwordHash), model.RememberMe, Session));
//GetUserInfo returns | separated string of user datas. "userId|userName|firstName|lastName" for example.
```

And at last, using all of the above in code

```
if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   int userId = ((MyIdentity)User.Identity).UserId;
}
```

This may seem the larger code, but in runtime it'll give much more benefits than storing all the data in session. The main of them are null checking and casting every time.

Comment: Have you got some reference explaining why: 'Session is not the way to check whether user is authenticated or not'? I would be very interested to read!

Comment: I don' have the exact reference so i'll try to explain it. Why is session always checked for nulls? One reason is because you don't exactly know when it may be cleared. Clear may be caused by recycling application pool, or it may be caused by low memory on server, etc. Once the user is authenticated, you certainly don't wish to lose his authentication when session is cleared - that may lead him to unexpected and unnecessary authentication requests every time. Session should be mainly populated with things that you are able to recover and store again if they're lost.

Comment: In your example the user will have to login again too. If you application pool gets recycled all sessions are lost no matter what you do (unless your using something other than InProc sessionstate). The things that are stored in session here are apparently specified on login so to me it makes perfectly sense to store these in Session.

Comment: In my example user data is stored in cookie. And cookie is stored in browser. Why will user have to login again?

Comment: Because his session is gone. If you authenticate users based on their userID what will happen if I get your userID (no matter how)? Will I be loggedin? If that's the case you have a major security leak. If I manage to 'steal' your cookie I can authenticate myself indefinetly as your user.

Comment: Yep, that is true if you can. That's same as if you could steal my credit card number, my password, etc. And it definitely matters how. If i give to you my password and username by will, that's not the security leak of an application you will use it in. Forms authentication encrypts the cookie as its maximum possible level by default and its practically impossible to leak that. And i didn't say that i authenticate them via user id, where did you get that? :). Only after they are authenticated by username and password, i get their user id from database and store them in cookie.

Comment: And stealing cookies is the problem of every single site on the web, no matter what data they contain. Because of that web sites try to not allow javascript injection, browsers restrict cross site data exchange, etc. That's done to maximally protect user cookies and other sensitive data.

Comment: @archil let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1917/discussion-between-thekip-and-archil)

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to store "loggedIn" in session.
you can use Session["userName"] to check, if it is null, not logged in; not null, logged in.

try to use one session item to track user login status, such username or userid.

also you can encapsule the logic into a method such as

```
static bool CheckLogin(HttpSession sessionState, out username, out userId, out firstName, out LastName);
```

FYI

Answer (score -3):

may be you need to use caching in your application because you are going to check if null or not every time i think for save use data caching will be better and here are some links :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsbfdd8c(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972379.aspx

http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/asp.net/caching-in-asp.net.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachingaspnet.aspx

Hope it helps mark as answered if it helps :)

Comment: How will caching solve a problem in session scope? Caching is application scope.

Comment: Why would you use caching with user authentication determination? that's simply misleading and not correct

Comment: for me i am using nhibernate i am using something like session but i have to store the user data in an object called user request and it will be with me all over the application that is why i am telling that

Comment: Session is something completely different in the context of NHIbernate. A session in NHibernate is something like a transaction (correct me if I'm wrong) in normal terms. This question is about Session in ASP.net which is an object which is created for each user to make sense of various requests belonging to the same 'user' (session).