# MasterPage Page_Load event triggers only after Content Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

How to add a code for all content Pages before content Page_Load event ? 
I tried adding it to masterPage Page_Load event. 
But, It triggers only after content Page_Load.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: See [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593652/asp-net-page-page-load-firing-before-master-pages-page-load-event)

Comment: Can you tell what is the exact requirement/scenario?

Comment: @JoeyCiechanowicz what code can I try in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try master page's `Page_Init` event.
See [Events in ASP.NET Master and Content Pages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3%28v=vs.140%29.aspx).